# How to solve Javascript map loop not working each div tag?

Tags: javascript, loops

Sometime I faced this problem, why not map loop working, I still did not get solution.

```
 let slide = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');

    //not working below
    slide.map((s)=>  s.onmousedown = slideFunction);

    function slideFunction(){
        alert('HI')
    }

    // working below
    let num = [3,2,5,2];
    num.map((n)=> alert(num));
```

the map loop not working each slide but num value array working.

Comment: console log slide and see if it has a value

Comment: please check this https://api.jquery.com/map/

Answer (score 2):

A couple of issues:

- You should not be using `map()` for this, but `forEach()`.
- The `document.querySelectorAll()` function returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not an array. You need to convert it to an array to call array functions like `map()` on it.
  *However*, `NodeList` does provide a [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) function, so you can invoke that directly on the result of `document.querySelectorAll()`.

```js
let slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');

slides.forEach((s) => s.onmousedown = slideFunction);

function slideFunction() {
  alert('Hi')
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">Slide one</div>
<div class="slide">Slide two</div>
```

It's probably also cleaner to attach an event handler instead of directly assigning the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

It is because querySelectorAll returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), it is an array-like object (it seems like an array but it is not).

You should convert it to an array:

```
Array.from(slide).map((s)=>  s.onmousedown = slideFunction);
```